# extract a string after a pattern

Tags: unix, sed, awk, pattern-matching

I want to extract the numbers following client_id and id and pair up client_id and id in each line.

For example, for the following lines of log,

```
User(client_id:03)) results:[RelatedUser(id:204, weight:10),_RelatedUser(id:491,_weight:10),_RelatedUser(id:29, weight: 20)

User(client_id:04)) results:[RelatedUser(id:209, weight:10),_RelatedUser(id:301,_weight:10)

User(client_id:05)) results:[RelatedUser(id:20, weight: 10)
```

I want to output

```
03 204
03 491
03 29
04 209
04 301
05 20
```

I know I need to use sed or awk. But I do not know exactly how.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a `awk` script that works (I put it on multiple lines and made it a bit more verbose so you can see what's going on):

```
#!/bin/bash

awk 'BEGIN{FS="[\(\):,]"}
/client_id/ {
cid="no_client_id"
for (i=1; i<NF; i++) {
    if ($i == "client_id") {
        cid = $(i+1)
    } else if ($i == "id") {
        id = $(i+1);
        print cid OFS id;
    }
 }
}' input_file_name
```

**Output:**

```
03 204
03 491
03 29
04 209
04 301
05 20
```

**Explanation:**

- `awk 'BEGIN{FS="[\(\):,]"}`: invoke `awk`, use `(` `)` `:` and `,` as delimiters to separate your fields
- `/client_id/ {`: Only do the following for the lines that contain `client_id`:
- `for (i=1; i<NF; i++) {`: iterate through the fields on each line one field at a time
- `if ($i == "client_id") { cid = $(i+1) }`: if the field we are currently on is `client_id`, then its value is the next field in order.
- `else if ($i == "id") { id = $(i+1); print cid OFS id;}`: otherwise if the field we are currently on is `id`, then print the `client_id : id` pair onto `stdout`
- `input_file_name`: supply the name of your input file as first argument to the `awk` script.

Comment: Nice one, but my gawk was complaining that it decided to ignore the `\` before the brackets. These can be safely removed

Comment: Not allowed to edit my own comment anymore... What I wanted to add: Within the character set characters (`[` and `]`), only the following are metacharacters that need to be escaped: `\^]-`.

Comment: A couple of suggestions: get rid of the null statements (trailing semi-colons) change `print cid OFS id` to simply `print cid, id` (it's what OFS exists for), don't put \ before ( and ) in the character set, and since the client_id is always at the same position you could simply set it to $3 and then loop starting at 4. See @steve's solution.

Comment: Sampson, Thanks for the detailed explanation. One more question, regarding the line /client_id/ {, if I write /client_id/ and { in two different lines, the output mixes the input file and the correct results. Why?

Comment: @jerry that's just part of `awk`'s syntax. The short answer is: if nothing precedes an outer-most `{` on the same line in awk's script, the instructions within the brackets will be executed for every line. For example `BEGIN{...}` means "only do this when script begins" `/pattern/ {...}` means only do this on the lines that have "pattern". The long and proper answer deserves an explanation too long for the comment box.

Answer (score 5):

This may work for you:

```
awk -F "[):,]" '{ for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) if ($i ~ /id/) print $2, $(i+1) }' file
```

Results:

```
03 204
03 491
03 29
04 209
04 301
05 20
```

Comment: +1 for FS-based approach but I think `'{print $2,$6}'` is all you need in the body.

Comment: Thanks Ed. I think a loop is needed because there are multiple "RelatedUsers". I think `$6` would only print the id of the first one.

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '/.*(\(client_id:([0-9]+))[^(]*\(id:([0-9]+)/!d;s//\2 \3\n\1/;P;D' file
```

- `/.*(\(client_id:([0-9]+))[^(]*\(id:([0-9]+)/!d` if the line doesn't have the intended strings delete it.
- `s//\2 \3\n\1/` re-arrange the line by copying the `client_id` and moving the first `id` ahead thus reducing the line for successive iterations.
- `P` print upto the introduced newline.
- `D` delete upto the introduced newline.

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer awk for this, but if you were wondering how to do this with sed, here's one way that works with GNU sed.

*parse.sed*

```
/client_id/ {
  :a
  s/(client_id:([0-9]+))[^(]+\(id:([0-9]+)([^\n]+)(.*)/\1 \4\5\n\2 \3/
  ta
  s/^[^\n]+\n//
}
```

Run it like this:

```
sed -rf parse.sed infile
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
<infile sed '/client_id/ { :a; s/(client_id:([0-9]+))[^(]+\(id:([0-9]+)([^\n]+)(.*)/\1 \4\5\n\2 \3/; ta; s/^[^\n]+\n//; }'
```

Output:

```
03 204
03 491
03 29

04 209
04 301

05 20
```

#### Explanation:

The idea is to repeatedly match `client_id:([0-9]+)` and `id:([0-9]+)` pairs and put them at the end of pattern space. On each pass the `id:([0-9]+)` is removed.

The final replace removes left-overs from the loop.

Comment: Thor, Thanks for the detailed explanation. One more question, regarding the line /client_id/ {, if I write /client_id/ and { in two different lines, the output mixes the input file and the correct results. Why?

Comment: @jerry: That's odd, here I get an error `sed: file parse.sed line 2: unknown command` followed by a newline. As far as I know the curly brace needs to be on the same line as the condition preceding it.