# How can I use the symbols [ and ] as field seperators for gawk?

Tags: gawk

*emphasized text*I have some text like

```
CreateMainPageLink("410",$objUserData,$mnt[139]);
```

from which i want to extract the number `139` after the occurrence of `mnt` with `gawk`. I tried the following expression (within a `pipe` expression to be used on a result of a `grep`)

```
gawk '{FS="[\[\]]";print NF}'
```

to print the number of fields. If my field separators were `[` and `]` I expect to see the number `3` printed out (three fields; one before the opening rectangular bracket, one after, and the actual number I want to extract). What I get instead is *one* field, corresponding to the full line, and two warnings:

```
gawk: warning: escape sequence `\[' treated as plain `['
gawk: warning: escape sequence `\]' treated as plain `]'
```

I was following the example given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13464932/extract-a-string-after-a-pattern), but obviously there is some problem/error with my expression.

Using the following two expressions also do not work:

```
gawk '{FS="[]"}{print NF;}'
gawk: (FILENAME=- FNR=1) fatal: Unmatched [ or [^: /[]/
```

and

```
gawk '{FS="\[\]"}{print NF;}'
gawk: warning: escape sequence `\[' treated as plain `['
gawk: warning: escape sequence `\]' treated as plain `]'
gawk: (FILENAME=- FNR=1) fatal: Unmatched [ or [^: /[]/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gawk -F[][] '{ print $0" -> "$1"\t"$2; }'

```
$ gawk -F[][] '{ print $0" -> "$1"\t"$2; }'
titi[toto]tutu
titi[toto]tutu -> titi  toto
```

1) You must set the `FS` before entering the main parsing loop. You could do:

```
awk  'BEGIN { FS="[\\[\\]]"; } { print $0" -> "$1"\t"$2; }'
```

Which executes the `BEGIN` clause before parsing the file.

I have to escape the `[`character twice: one because it is inside a quoted string. And another once because gawk mandate it inside a bracket expression.

I personnaly prefer to use the `-F` flag which is less verbose.

2) `FS="[\[\]]"` is wrong, because you are inside a quoted string, this escape the character inside the string. Awk will see: `[[]]` which is an invalid bracket expression.

3) `FS="[]"` is wrong because it is an empty bracket expression trying to match nothing

4) `FS="\[\]"` is wrong again because it is error 2) and 3) together :)

gawk manual says: `The regular expressions in awk are a superset of the POSIX specification`. This is why you can use either: `[\\[\\]]` or `[][]`. The later being the posix way.

*To include a literal ']' in the list, make it the first character*

See:

- Posix Regex specification:
  http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_04
- Posix awk specification:
  http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/awk.html
- Gnu Awk manual:
  http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Bracket-Expressions

Comment: Thanks for this solution, which seem to work. But do you also have an explanation why your solution works and what is wrong with mine?

Comment: In the man page link you describe it is said, that to include a single ']' within a bracket expression one has to escape it. But escaping it once is, as we have seen on this question, wrong. You either don't escape it or escape it twice. Both are contradictory to the man page. What am I missing?

Comment: @Alex By posix: You don't escape it and make it first character. By awk extension to posix: you escape twice if inside a quoted string or only once if outside a quoted string.

Comment: I do not understand your comment. The man page says: "This treatment of ‘\’ in bracket expressions is compatible with other awk implementations and is also mandated by POSIX."

Comment: @Alex you're right this is what awk manual states. But I can't find it in the POSIX spec: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_03_05

Comment: @Alex This is specified in the awk specification, not in the regex specification: *except that it shall allow the use of C-language conventions for escaping special characters within the EREs,* http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/awk.html

Answer (score 1):

`FS="[]"` Here it looks for data inside the `[]` and there are none.

To use square brackets you need to write them like this `[][]`

This is also wrong `gawk '{FS="[\[\]]";print NF}'` you need FS as a variable outside expression.

Eks

```
echo 'CreateMainPageLink("410",$objUserData,$mnt[139]);' | awk -F[][] '{print $2}'
139
```

Or

```
awk  '{print $2}' FS=[][]
```

Or

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS="[][]"} {print $2}'
```

All gives `139`

Edit: `gawk '{FS="[\[\]]";print NF}'` Here you print number of fields `NF` and not value of it `$NF`. Anyway it will not help, since dividing your data with `[]` gives `);` as last filed, use this `awk  '{print $(NF-1)}' FS=[][]` to get second last filed.

Comment: Is the use of [][] documented somewhere? How could I have found out? Is this a special case just for rectangular brackets? I cannot found any useful reference on the gawk man pages...

Comment: Its some thing you learn :)  But this `[` starts and this `]` stops a range.  So adding `[[]]`, you get two start groups and two stops group. So only correct way to do it is `[][]` or `"[][]"`.  Google is your friend..   You can also use `FS="\\\[|\\\]"` or `FS="[\\\[\\\]]"`but looks ugly.

Comment: @Alex It's specified in the man page for posix regular expressions. see the links in my answer

Comment: @Jotne: When [ starts and ] stops a range, [][] means two empty ranges to me. After the start sign comes the stop sign; this is repeated once. So either your explanation is not entirely correct and logic, or I am missing something else.

Comment: You are correct, but this is the way they have made awk.  I think you will remember this next time you have brackets :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you need `awk`?  You can get the value via `sed` like this:

```
 # echo 'CreateMainPageLink("410",$objUserData,$mnt[139]);' | sed -n 's:.*\[\([0-9]\+\)\].*:\1:p'
 139
```

Comment: Thanks for your input; your suggestion seem to work, but I would like to know why my gawk expression is not working. Also , I do not understand what the sed command is exactly doing. If you could explain the different parts that would be great.